# Ubiquiti UniFi (UAP) for 30~40 clients

Tags: networking, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

we're working on a small business with ~40 programmers using Internet all-day, this means web, mail, Skype and some video conference.
Now we're going to install the wireless network to provide conectivity for ~40 people.

Is the Ubiquiti UniFi capable to handle up to 30 or 40 wireless clients?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can it handle 40 Clients... Depends entirely on what their doing. I'd guess yes. But really, it depends on your clients, what they're doing, your physical environment, interference from other APs/networks, interference from other sources (like microwave ovens, yes this really happens).

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your fast reply. The clients works entirely with Skype and some github (cloning & pushing), there aren't interference problems and all clients are very close to the AP place